# Testing loop after SSO login on a website

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, automated-tests

I am working on a ASP.NET website and there is an occasional problem after succesfull SSO login. Requests and responses are coming from my website, to SSO website, then to my website again and then to SSO login and so on.. I'm sure that login was succesfull. Most of the time this works correctly but sometimes there is this loop. I would like to write a program, which should try to login every 10 minutes and send me an email if the loop occurred.

Are there any tools to test scenario like this in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I made it with [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) which is very nice framework for auto tested websites.